# $||f|| = \int_0^1 |f(x)| dx$ and $||.||_{\infty}$ are not equivalent norms

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

> Show that the following function defines a norm in $C[0,1]$ which is
>   not equivalent to the norm $||.||_{\infty}$:
>
> $$||f|| = \int_0^1 |f(x)| dx$$

$$\int_0^1 ||f(x)|| = 0\implies f(x) = 0\mbox{ for all $x\in [0,1]$}$$

The triangle inequality follows from the triangle inequality from $|a+b|\le |a|+|b|$ but with function images in place of the absolute value number. Also $\int_0^1|\alpha f(x)| dx = \alpha \int_0^1|f(x)|\ dx$ so it is indeed a norm.

Now, $||f(x)||_{\infty} = \sup_{x\in [0,1]} \{f(x)\}$

In order to show that it's not equivlent to the norm $||.||$, I must show there are no constants $a,b>0$, such that

$$a||f||_{\infty} \le ||f||\le b||f||_{\infty}$$

Suppose that there are, so we have

$$a\sup_{x\in [0,1]}f(x) \le \int_0^1 |f(x)| dx\le b\sup_{x\in [0,1]}f(x)$$

I think

$$\int_0^1 |f(x)| dx\le \int_0^1 \sup_{x\in [0,1]} f(x) \ dx = \int_0^1 \ dx \sup_{x\in [0,1]} f(x) = b \sup_{x\in [0,1]} f(x)$$

I think I can see $a\sup_{x\in [0,1]}f(x) \le \int_0^1 |f(x)| dx$ happening. Why it cannot be true for some very small $a$?

Comment: Those constants $a,b$ must be s.t the inequalities hold for all elements in the domain i.e $C[0,1]$ If you assume such a $a$ exists, you can construct a continuous function who's integral over $[0,1]$ is less than $a sup f$, just sketch it out, let $f(0)=M$ for sufficiently large $M$ and then a sufficiently steep line to $0$ and f identically $0$ elsewhere in the domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f_n(x)=1-nx$ for $0<x<\frac 1 n$ and $0$ for all other $x$.  What is $\|f_n\|_{\infty}$ and $\|f_n\|_1$ ?.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: think about a function that is "mostly" zero except for a very sharp spike.